Creating Unique User Stories across the team, how to map the dates in Scrum since multiple dates cannot be added for same item
Consider I have 3 User stories, now would like to group them for development & QA.
If going ahead with same user stories which have adequate information how to add the due dates since it varies for departments & how to link upfront for Development & QA.
I was planning to split the User stories for development & map them individually in Jira.
Please suggest Best practice.


What exactly is a due date in terms of Scrum? Why do you have multiple development stages with due dates? By the book, I would assume a story is "In Sprint 7", which means both a suggested start as well as a best estimate of it's end date for all parties involved. If you consider QA to be outside of the Scrum team, then it also is their earliest start date.

A story is a work unit. Multiple people can be working on it. So, it would be best if you did not create a story per phase for the same requirement; you can use tasks and subtasks under a story to assign the work to the developers (including both software developers and QA).
The "due date", as @novigt mentioned in their comment, is not a valid term in Scrum. If you want to use them, tasks and subtasks have the "Start Date/End Date" fields for you to use.

Now everything got clear! Thanks for your time.

You’re welcome
